# Copy a particular string from multiple lines of output and assign it to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

When I run a `serverstatus.sh` command for `WebSphere` I get the following output

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Server1/logs/serverStatus.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the Server1 profile
ADMU0503I: Retrieving server status for all servers
ADMU0505I: Servers found in configuration:
ADMU0506I: Server name: server1
ADMU0508I: The Application Server "server1" is STARTED
```

I want to copy a particular string called "server1" and assign it to a variable using `shell` scripts.

Comment: Do you want each line returned if it contains "server1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a straight forward `GNU awk` like this,

```
serverName=$( ./serverstatus.sh | awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '/Server name/{print $3; exit}')
echo "$serverName"
server1
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain what this line did "awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '". I am new to shell script and trying to learn at the same time.

Comment: That sets the input delimiter for the string as a colon character followed by one or more number of blank spaces